# Store variables online and retrieve it in Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, database

Are there any online services/servers that could store information like:

```
username
email
company information
```

So that it could be retrieved by Ruby script?

Comment: what database? Question is tagged database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple key/value store in the cloud check out [Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)

For complex relational data use a database. If you want a database in the cloud check-out [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/).

Comment: Also, check-out this article on using SimpleDB with Ruby http://geekin.gs/using-amazon-aws-simpledb-with-ruby-roundup

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are also known as [databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system).

You can set up your own db if you have a server, or you can try and find someone who will host databases for you  (try Googling "Free MySQL" for example)

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is an online server that stores your variables, properties, files online and allows you to retrieve them via kind of API.

Answer (score 1):

With a small amount of knowledge about how git works, you could easily set up a 1-file rack or Sinatra application on heroku to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenKeyval](http://openkeyval.org/) Simple Key/Value storage. And it's Free. Not secure though.